# How do I write an SQL query with a WHERE = 'all'?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a PHP script which takes a JSON request containing a parameter known as `bookTypeID`.

This `bookTypeID` parameter can have either an integer value (e.g. 1,2,3,4) or a string value of "all".

I use this parameter as an input to the WHERE clause of an SQL query.

I want my query to say `SELECT name FROM books WHERE $bookTypeID`, which would work fine if `$bookTypeID` is an integer, but I do not know a correct value to pass to the `WHERE` clause in the case where the JSON parameter has the value "all". I want something which essentially says "ignore the WHERE clause".

I hope this makes sense. I have posted a simplified version of my code below:

```
 <?php

  include 'db_conf.php';

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
  }

  $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json = json_decode($content, true);

  $bookTypeIDString = $json["bookTypeID"];
  $bookTypeID;
  switch($bookTypeIDString){
    case "all":
      $bookTypeID = "all"; // IS THERE A VALUE HERE THAT I CAN PASS TO AN SQL QUERY TO RETURN EVERYTHING? i.e. IGNORE THE WHERE CLAUSE COMPLETELY?
      break;
    default:
      $bookTypeID = $bookTypeIDString;
  }

  $query = "SELECT name FROM books WHERE booktype = $bookTypeID";
  $result = $conn->query($query);

  $data = array();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($data);

  $conn->close();
?>
```

Update: This is a simplified example for the purpose of asking my question. In practice, I have about 50 parameters passed via the JSON, so I would like to avoid building up an SQL statement using conditional PHP. I am hoping for an SQL value that I can pass which will return everything.

Comment: Um, just remove the where clause? You do realize PHP is a dynamic language and you can dynamically build that query. If you don't want a where clause then simply don't add one.

Comment: you can append your where clause in **default:** case in your switch and in **case "all"** case, your **$bookTypeID** value should be blank.

Comment: `"SELECT name FROM books WHERE booktype = $bookTypeID OR $bookTypeID = 'all'";` (of course, assuming `booktype` is a string, but if it's not, you can use a similar logic)

Comment: `WHERE 1=1` and add the other statemends only if you Need them

Comment: @craig please have a look on my answer let me know if it solves ur issue

Comment: `case "all":  $bookTypeID = "booktype"`. result: `where booktype=booktype` always true (if booktype is not null) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Removing the WHERE altogether would be best.**

Just for fun, you could do

```
case "all":
  $bookTypeID = "booktype"; 
  break;
```

so that the SQL ends up as

```
WHERE booktype = booktype
```

which is the same as

```
WHERE booktype IS NOT NULL
```

which may work for you.

Essentially, you are SQL-injecting yourself here (goes to show that this JSON data must not come from untrusted input).

Comment: Maybe. But still: Please just remove the WHERE altogether.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your SQL Query based on what kind of Input/Type $bookTypeID is. So just append the where claus if needed.

This way, you don't have to change your databasefields and keep your workflow at this point consistent.

```
if($bookTypeID == 'all') {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM books";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM books WHERE booktype = $bookTypeID";
}
```

Comment: Code dumps are *bad answers*. You should explain *why* this solves their problem.

Comment: While your solution works, my problem is that, in practice, I have 50 different parameters, so I am trying to avoid "statement building" using conditional PHP - which would result in 50! permutations.

Comment: I thought you only have an json with numbers or 'all'? 
So there should be no problem using the above. 
The If statements only checks if the variable contains 'all'. If not always do the second one.

Comment: For the purpose of my question, I provided a simplified example which one had 1 variable being passed in the JSON.

In practice, I have 50 variables being passed e.g. `bookTypeID`, `publisherID`, `ISDN`, `title`, `author`, etc. All of these values can be 'all' or have a real value.

My SQL query is therefore more like `$query = "SELECT name FROM books WHERE booktype = $bookTypeID AND publisher = $publisher AND author = $author AND title = $title`.

Comment: I essentially need a way of ignoring a particular condition within the WHERE clause if the value of the JSON parameter is set to 'all'. I was hoping that there was an SQL solution rather than a PHP one.

Comment: Now i got it. I'm sorry for missunderstanding your question. And there is a way: but sadly still not sql based.
use an loop to go over every part of your json.
and append based on the current loopvalue. 

But by the look at it and thinking about it, you should try to optimise your database, or the way your json is created.

Answer (score 1):

use below way  update your switch case and query string

```
$where = '';
switch($bookTypeIDString){
    case "all":
      $bookTypeID = "all"; // IS THERE A VALUE HERE THAT I CAN PASS TO AN SQL QUERY TO RETURN EVERYTHING? i.e. IGNORE THE WHERE CLAUSE COMPLETELY?

     break;
    default:
      $bookTypeID = $bookTypeIDString;
       $where = "WHERE booktype = $bookTypeID";  
  }

$query = "SELECT name FROM books ".$where;
```

or you can use

```
$where = '';
if($bookTypeID != 'all') {
    $where = "WHERE booktype = $bookTypeID"; 
}
$query = "SELECT name FROM books ".$where;
```

Hope you understands it as where clause should come for bookTypeID otherwise all so just make and $where clause and append empty if condition in all otherwise where clause in $where

Comment: Code dumps are *bad answers*. You should explain *why* this solves their problem.

Comment: yhea  buddy but it's simple just a clause omit if condition unmatches.

Comment: While your solution works for that specific example, my problem is that, in practice, I have 50 different parameters, so I am trying to avoid "statement building" using conditional PHP - which would result in 50! permutations.

Comment: For the purpose of my question, I provided a simplified example which one had 1 variable being passed in the JSON. In practice, I have 50 variables being passed e.g. bookTypeID, publisherID, ISDN, title, author, etc. All of these values can be 'all' or have a real value. My SQL query is therefore more like $query = "SELECT name FROM books WHERE booktype = $bookTypeID AND publisher = $publisher AND author = $author AND title = $title

Comment: I essentially need a way of ignoring a particular condition within the WHERE clause if the value of the JSON parameter is set to 'all'. I was hoping that there was an SQL solution rather than a PHP one.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this . 
Here we replace the whole where clause -> if "all" then no where clause 
if "bookTypeId" then we use a where clause

```
  switch($bookTypeIDString){
    case "all":
      $bookTypeID = ""; 
      break;
    default:
      $WhereStting = "WHERE booktype = $bookTypeIDString";
  }

  $query = "SELECT name FROM books $WhereStting";
```

Comment: Code dumps are *bad answers*. You should explain *why* this solves their problem.

Comment: why so ? i have replaced the where clause as a string

Comment: You replaced on the variable `$booktype`, not the whole WHERE clause. So now the query will only look for booktypes with no value which will return no rows. That is a defect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121740/discussion-between-vikrant-vir-bhalla-and-john-conde).

Comment: I am happy that your example works in my simplified example, but in practice I have around 50 parameters that are passed in my JSON, so I am trying to avoid 'statement building' using PHP.

Are you able to improve your solution by offering a simply way that works for a large number parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Where clause is used to filter the data, in your case you are using bookTypeID for filter, for all you don't need to add a where clause. For that you can separate the query by sub query and concat it using php.
Please look the correction for all

```
    <?php

  include 'db_conf.php';

  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
  }

  $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json = json_decode($content, true);

  $bookTypeIDString = $json["bookTypeID"];
  $bookTypeID;
  switch($bookTypeIDString){
    case "all":
      $bookTypeID = "all"; // IS THERE A VALUE HERE THAT I CAN PASS TO AN SQL QUERY TO RETURN EVERYTHING? i.e. IGNORE THE WHERE CLAUSE COMPLETELY?
      $where_clause = " ";
      break;
    default:
      $bookTypeID = $bookTypeIDString;
      $where_clause = " WHERE booktype = $bookTypeID";
  }

  $query = "SELECT name FROM books".$where_clause;
  $result = $conn->query($query);

  $data = array();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($data);

  $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Code dumps are *bad answers*. You should explain *why* this solves their problem.

Comment: Why have a separate `if` after the `switch` ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may not need an additional logic in php code to do this. You can just say

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM books WHERE (booktype = $bookTypeID OR $bookTypeID = 'all' )"
```

Comment: This is the type of thing that I am looking for, but I find that it returns 0 rows in the case where $bookTypeID = "all" (rather than returning all rows).

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue like that however?Did you try exactly what I wrote or something similar to this? Maybe its related to php data types for the variable bookTypeID but I cannot say anything for sure without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all records, need not to use **WHERE** clause.

But if you need records with specified SET of bookTypeId you may use **IN**.

Like

> $query = "SELECT name FROM books WHERE booktype IN ('1','2','3','4','5')";